# Creating Land Use Change Map in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, cartography

I need to create a map with multiple dataframes showing the percent change in land use - one each for agriculture, developed, and forest. Percent change has to be labeled on each county and color coded for increase, decrease, and no change.  I have the data figured out and ready to map.

I can't get started with creating the map and was wondering if you could give me a boost.

How can I separate the fields and just map the data picked from the table shown?

I included a screen capture of the table and basic county map.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

[image]

Comment: just to make sure : do you mean "label" as a text, or as a symbol for your polygon ?

Comment: By perhaps reading a little too much into your question, there's an additional symbology trick you can use for your labels. By making use of [Label Classes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Using_label_classes_to_label_features_from_the_same_layer_differently/00s80000000v000000/), you could set it up so your decrease labels are red, increase green, and no change are black. Note this is separate from symbolizing the actual county shape - and a red label on a red shape isn't going to show up without a background mask.

Comment: Did either of our answers help you out @user30728? or do you still need help with this? Please mark an answer as the solution if we got you where you needed to be. Alternately please leave a comment asking for more specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm making this too simple in my head, but I would [double click the layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000031000000) on which you need to label %change, and go to the Labels tab, turn on labels and select the correct field to display.

Then, in the same properties window, go to [symbology and symbolize based on your %complete field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Drawing_a_layer_using_categories/00s50000003m000000/).

I don't quite understand your statement about isolating fields and mapping the data picked from the table. You can filter based on a [Definition Query](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000002z000000) to restrict the entire table to a query, or you can make your symbols only display if they meet a certain criteria. [You can also label based on certain criteria.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s80000000v000000)

Comment: It might be helpful to expand your answer's symbology section. Asker wants to create a three color choropleth; just picking the % change field won't work since it could all be unique values. Granted, you could add unique values and symbolize all positive values one way, 0 another, and negative a third, but that's not terribly efficient. To use such a method it might be better to create three new fields that would hold values like 'increase', 'decrease', and 'no change', then symbolize on *those*. I think the "isolating fields" refers to creating three separate maps from the same table.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create your different Data Frames (3 total I assume). Just use the Insert Menu to insert a new data frame. Copy the LU Change layer into each data frame (you can just drag it down). Open Layout View to organize the different data frames they way you want them.

Next symbolize the different copies of the same layer based on the pctChg_dev field in one, pctChg_ag in another, and pctChg_for in the other. Choose your symbology for all of them based on "Quantities" in the symbolize tab. Right click the layer, go to properties, choose the symbology tab, and choose "Quantities" on the left, then choose your field to base the symbology on.

**EDIT** (additional info): You will want to use a Manual Classification using 3 classes for less than 0, equal to zero, and greater than zero. Hope that helps.

You will also want to label the counties by right-clicking the layers and choosing Properties and then go the the "Labels" tab and choose the same field that you used in the symbology (pctChg_dev, pctChg_ag, and pctChg) and be sure you check the box.

Comment: I would probably set up one layer completely first, then copy it to the other data frames. That way you only have to go in and edit any references to the fields, rather than set *everything* up three times. Saves time and helps with consistency. Also, since asker needs basically three symbols (ie classes), you might want to expand on a bit on using the Quantities symbology to get the desired ranges (+, -, and 0) because it won't be as simple as just pointing at the relevant field.

Comment: Agreed. Setting one layer up first may expedite things. The field will still need to be changed but if you chose your classifier (equal intervals or quantiles might be good for data based on a %). Then that would be re-used when setting up the other data frames.